# Reverse engineering Crontab string

Tags: c#, cron

I'm using Ncrontab in a C# web application. Currently, I have a view with a series of textboxes, checkboxes, and drop downs to create a crontab schedule. However, what I need to be able to do, for the purposes of allowing the user to edit their schedule, is take a crontab string and fill out the view appropriately.

Take this string for example:

```
0 */4 * * *
```

I need to be able to break that down, select 'Hourly' from a drop down, and fill in '4' in the a textbox (occurs every 'x' hours). In other words, I need to be able to do the opposite of what [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com) does.

I've been poking around Google and the likes, and seen a few references to Quartz.NET, but I'm not sure that has the functionality that I need. Any suggestions?

edit: I suppose I'm asking if there's a more efficient way to do this without a bunch of conditionals and string comparisons. Is there a library I should know about, or should I just roll up my sleeves and start parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have never used it but [**CronExpressionDescriptor**](http://www.geekytidbits.com/cron-expression-descriptor/) seems to be what you're looking for, [**click here to see a live demo**](http://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/).

[CronExpressionDescriptor on GitHub](https://github.com/bradyholt/cron-expression-descriptor)

[CronExpressionDescriptor on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CronExpressionDescriptor/)

Comment: It looks like I might be able to adapt that for my purposes. It would, at least, make parsing a little easier. Let me look into this before I mark this as the answer. Regardless, thank you!

Comment: @Woods8460 yw, besides that I guess you could make your own helper I don't think it would be that difficult you mainly need to validate it and you can easily break it apart to do so.

Comment: I think that may be the way I have to go. I may just use the CronExpressionDescriptor as a base and make my own helper. I'm going to mark this as the answer since it's at least given me something to look at. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

... a little addition that may help someone:

It occurred to me that in the *ncrontab* format used for example in Azure there is an extra position for **seconds**!

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions

vs.

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * <command to execute>
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron